# React event handler inheritance

Tags: reactjs, dom, event-handling

So I wrote a component with an event handler that is supposed to get the id of the element and it's parentNode. My code looks something like this:

```
class Schedule extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);



this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
    }

handleSelect(e){
    let week = e.target.parentNode.id;
    let day = e.target.id;

    this.props.onSelect(week, day);
}

render(){
    let schedObj = this.props.meal;

    let sched = schedObj.map(weekArr => weekArr.map((dayArr, ind1) => 
        <td id={ind1} className={"div"+ind1} onClick={this.handleSelect}>{dayArr.map(item => <p>{item.rName}</p>)}</td>));

    return(
        <div>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                <tr id="0">
                    {sched[0]}
                </tr>
                <tr id="1">
                    {sched[1]}
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}

 }
```

Ideally, e.target.id would be the id for the div, and e.target.parentNode.id would be the id for the tr. However, when I click on it, it will occaisionally give me the id of the p within the div as the e.target.id, and the for the  as the e.target.parentNode.id. I'm guessing since the p is nested within the div, the handleSelect(e) event handler still applies to it. How can I get this to only work for the div and not its children?

Comment: i don't see any `<div/>` element in the template

Comment: It doesn't really make sense for an `onClick` of a parent to not apply to the children. A better way is to just to define the `onClick` with arguments when creating the elements, rather than using event targets and element ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have defined an onClick on the td element, and you have a `<p>` tag inside of td, need to use `e.currentTarget.id` to get the id of the `td`

```
handleSelect(e){
    let week = e.target.parentNode.id;
    let day = e.currentTarget.id;

    this.props.onSelect(week, day);
}
```

`currentTarget` gives you the element on which the handler is defined, while `target` gives you the element on which the event happened and since you have a `p` inside `td` it may so happen that you clicked on the `<p>` tag and hence you do not get the `id` of `<td>` element `onClick`